# regular points of locally one-to-one $C^1$ map

Tags: calculus

Assume $\Omega$ is an open set, and $\varphi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is  continuously differentiable ($\varphi \in C^1(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$) and locally one-to-one, then how to prove its regular point is not empty? That is, prove
$$\Omega_r=\{x\in\Omega\mid\mbox{det}\ \varphi'(x)\neq 0\}$$ is not empty.

I try to use the one-to-one condition to create some contradiction but failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the inverse function theorem to prove that. If φ is C1 and locally one-to-one, then for any x in Ω, there is a neighborhood U of x such that φ(U) is open and φ|U is one-to-one. Then by the inverse function theorem, φ|U has a C1 inverse on φ(U). this implies that detφ′(x) is nonzero for any x in U, since the derivative of the inverse is the reciprocal of the original derivative. So U is a subset of Ωr, which means Ωr is not empty.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).